# Android JsonObject parsing string with double quotes

Tags: android, json

Im using JsonObject to parse a response from an API, the problem is that the resulting String have double quotes, how to get string with no quotes?

```
                JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(response);
                JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
                String authorization = jobject.get("authorization").toString();

                Log.d("mensa","parseado jwt :"+authorization);
```

so my response looks like...

> parseado jwt :"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciO..."

Actual Json response

```
{
    "authorization": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1..."
}
```

what is the right way to parse this string so i dont get it wrapped with double quotes?

Comment: your json seems good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trim out the quotes: `authorization = authorization.substring(1, authorization.length() - 1)`
Edit: You should actually use the `getString()` method as it will return the actual content as a string, however, the above still works as a quick workaround.

Comment: no need to trim out the quotes. gson library provide methods to get actual value

Comment: @skadoosh should be the accepted answer!! this is a bad implementation

Answer (score 9):

I believe you are using GSON library. No need to trim out your result, gson provide methods for that. try this

```
 String authorization = jobject.get("authorization").getAsString();
```

Refer Gson API Doc : [JsonElement](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html)

Comment: when call getAsString after get call, the result is correct, there is just one pair double quotes

Answer (score 4):

You are getting Object from Json and then converting to String. `jobject.get("authorization").toString();` try to get String.

```
String authorization = jobject.getString("authorization");
```